# How to press send on 6 browser windows running gmail?

Tags: browser, autohotkey

We are doing a blinded trial on email forwarding, to see what kind of messages users will forward to their friends.

We need to fire off the emails at once ideally.  Is there a way to press send on 6 browsers windows on Gmail at once?

(2 x Firefox windows, normal and private)
(2 x Chrome, normal and incognito)
etc.

Or do we just get 6 people on 6 PCs to press send?

Answer (score 0):

Yes in Autohotkey you can do that.
Expect a couple of milliseconds gap betwen clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider would be delayed send. While gmail does not support it by default, it is possible to add with tools like https://code.google.com/p/gmail-delay-send/

Using this you could batch larger numbers of messages to all be sent at the same time.

If you use this I suggest [running your own instance](https://code.google.com/p/gmail-delay-send/wiki/GmailDelaySendOwnInstance_8).